# Plumbing and filtering for git diff same file between 2 branches

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to run `git diff` to obtain only the deleted lines in the same file `object.json` comparing my `feature` branch to `dev` branch.

For example:

```
feature branch object.json
{
  "foo1": "bar1"
}


dev branch object.json
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2"
}
```

Desired output (or similar):

```
- "foo2": "bar2"
```

I've tried running the following:

```
git diff --diff-filter=D feature dev -- object.json
```

But the `diff-filter` flag does not seem to work. Furthermore, it only gives a porcelain output which requires processing to be piped.

Is there a way I can achieve both filtering and converting this to plumbing with just git built-in options ? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) `--diff-filter=D` filters deleted *files*, not deleted *lines*. All those filter options only operate on the file level. I guess you are stuck with some `grep` calls to keep only the lines of the diff output you want, i.e. only the lines starting with a `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff feature:path/to/object.json dev:path/to/object.json \
| sed -n '/^@@/,/^diff/ { /^-/p }'
```

Git doesn't re-implement the entire Unix text-processing toolbox because doing that would just make more work for everyone, for nothing.

Comment: I tried this, but getting an error `sed: 1: "/^@@/,/^diff/ { /^-/p }": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: Okay, try it with a semicolon after the p or failing that a hard newline, very old `sed`s are lacking some conveniences.

Comment: That works, thanks! Can you please give insight to what the `{ /^-/p }` part of the regex means ?

Comment: inside the braces is a nested set of commands that only apply in the selected range. So `/^-/` is just another pattern to check on lines in that range, `p` prints the matching lines.

Comment: I ran into a related issue - git counts adding a line as deleting the old line, and re-adding the old and new line, so the old line shows as deleted. Is there a way I can filter this so the result only shows true deleted lines ?

Comment: can you ask that as a new question and include the diff it shows you? There's a lot of judgement calls in choosing the best possible representation of any change, so including  the actual hunk and all the context around it is best.  Feel free to @ me in a comment on the question.